# dynamic aggregations with data.table in R using derived column names

Tags: r, data.table

I have this data.table with different column types.

I do not know the column names before hand and I would like to generate aggregations only for columns of certain type (say, numeric). How to achieve this with data.table?

For example, consider the below code:

```
dt <- data.table(ch=c('a','b','c'),num1=c(1,3,6), num2=1:9)
```

Need to create a function that accepts the above data.table and automatically performs calculations on the numeric fields grouped by the character filed (say sum on num1 and mean on num2, by ch). How to achieve this dynamically?

We can find out the numeric columns using `sapply(dt, is.numeric)` but it gives column names as strings - not sure how to plug it with data.table. Help is appreciated. Below code gives the idea of what is required - but does not work

```
DoSomething <- function(dt)
{
    numCols <- names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.numeric)]
    chrCols <- names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.character)]
    dt[,list(sum(numCols[1]), mean(numCols[2])), by=(chrCols), with=F]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using `.SDcols` argument. See example.

```
require(data.table)

dt <- data.table(ch=c('a','b','c'), num1=c(1,3,6), num2=1:9)

DoSomething <- function(dt) {
    numCols <- names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.numeric)]
    chrCols <- names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.character)]
    dt[, list(sum(.SD[[1]]), mean(.SD[[2]])), by = chrCols, .SDcols = numCols]
}

DoSomething(dt)
```

Comment: Works great. I will look into this .SD workings. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: quick follow-up question: how to retain all columns after the `dt[,,]` I have other factor columns in the dt that are missing after this.

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem, how would you like to see them? As `by` variables?

Comment: Ok. Here is the problem. My dt consists of four columns {num1, num2, ch, fac1} of types {numeric, numeric, character, factor}. My problem is - say, I need to add +1 to all numbers and retain everything else same. So its a transformation. Now thanks to your .SDcols tip I am able to do add +1 to all my numbers using `dt[,lapply(.SD,function(x) x+1), .SDcols=c('num1','num2')]`. In this particular case, I am not using `by` since its not an aggregation (which I have to do as next step). But after this increment, I have no more ch or fac1 column in the output left for aggregation. Any pointers,pls.

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem There is a solution. The best would be if you could ask a new question on this, as it is out of scope if the current question.

Answer (score 1):

@djhurio gives a nice solution to your problem.

`.SD` and `.SDcols` in `data.table` gives what you want.

In case you perform same calculation between different columns, you can try the following code.

```
require(data.table)

dt <- data.table(ch=c('a','b','c'), num1=c(1,3,6), num2=1:9)

DTfunction <- function(dt){
    numCols <- names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.numeric)]
    chrCols <- names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.character)]
    dt <- dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = (chrCols), .SDcols = (numCols)]
}
```

cute code. Isn't it? :)

Comment: Please check your code. There isn't `by` argument for `lapply` nor to `mean`.

Comment: I guess he meant, `dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = chrCols, .SDcols = (numCols)]`

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem true. And the `DTfunction` returns `NULL` in this example.